# Problem with my wifi

Tags: wireless

I just install the 13.04 ubuntu desktop, but my wifi donot work

```
orlando@HP-ENVY:~$ ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  direcciónHW 84:34:97:15:ff:08  
          Direc. inet:192.168.1.1  Difus.:192.168.1.255  Másc:255.255.255.0
          Dirección inet6: fe80::8634:97ff:fe15:ff08/64 Alcance:Enlace
          ACTIVO DIFUSIÓN FUNCIONANDO MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Métrica:1
          Paquetes RX:94865 errores:0 perdidos:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          Paquetes TX:74758 errores:0 perdidos:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          colisiones:0 long.colaTX:1000 
          Bytes RX:105177752 (105.1 MB)  TX bytes:10045323 (10.0 MB)

lo        Link encap:Bucle local  
          Direc. inet:127.0.0.1  Másc:255.0.0.0
          Dirección inet6: ::1/128 Alcance:Anfitrión
          ACTIVO BUCLE FUNCIONANDO  MTU:65536  Métrica:1
          Paquetes RX:2491 errores:0 perdidos:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          Paquetes TX:2491 errores:0 perdidos:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          colisiones:0 long.colaTX:0 
          Bytes RX:273944 (273.9 KB)  TX bytes:273944 (273.9 KB)
```

Some one can help me?

Comment: Include result  of `lspci`, `sudo lshw -c network` & `rfkill list all`

Answer (score 0):

Try to activate the wifi module

```
sudo ifconfig wlan0 up
```

or connect your pc with the ethernet cable and then install the proprietary drivers.